# How can I drag rows from a DataGrid and drop them in Excel?

Tags: excel, flash, apache-flex, drag-and-drop, flex3

I'd like to be able to drag and drop from a DataGrid in a Flash application into an Excel spreadsheet.  Is this possible?  If so, how do I implement this?

**Edit:** Nine days without so much as a comment is pushing me to believe one of the following things:

1. This question is so easy to answer that everyone who reads it thinks, "Ah, the next guy will get it.  This taco isn't gonna eat itself."
2. No one knows what Microsoft Excel is.
3. I'm so inept at coding for Flash that everyone who reads this question promptly dies from a stroke brought on by uncontrollable, hysterical laughter.  Kind of like what happens when a person is exposed to the Joker's laughing gas.
4. The entire internet has been suddenly and completely vacated creating a vast, digital wasteland (except for me, obviously).
5. Adobe's PR person in charge of their Twitter account recently posted something highly offensive and everyone has finally gotten organized and successfully boycotted something without inviting me to the party.

Anyone want to clue me in to which one is, in fact, the truth?

Or maybe just tell me that what I want is stupid/impossible/not worth the effort?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no, it is not possible. Have you ever coded AS4? I spent 6 months coding stupid loops that randomly draw colored lines. It was terrible. Get out while you still can. I was coding some tangents outside by my school when a couple of engineering grads started making trouble. I coded one bad batch and my professor said "You're moving with the retards to coding 101" I hopped on my segway and rode home. I then hung myself.

Comment: Flagged as "totally freaking awesome".